# Parse XML with XmlPullParser

Tags: android, xml

I have a XML file like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<training>
    <lesson name="Set_01">
        <exercise>
            <param controller="Training01"/>
            <param form="Training01"/>
            <param table="voctrain"/>
            <param subset="0,62"/>
            <param template="clicks"/>
            <param description="0101_0"/>
        </exercise>
        <exercise>
            <param controller="Training02"/>
            <param form="Training02"/>
            <param table="voctrain"/>
            <param subset="0,62"/>
            <param template="clicks"/>
            <param description="0101_1"/>
            <param sound="N"/>
            <param mode="DE"/>
            <param count="80"/>
        </exercise>
        <exercise>
            ...
        </exercise>
        <exercise>
        ...
        </exercise>
    </lesson>
    <lesson name="Set_02">
        <exercise>
        ...
        </exercise>
        <exercise>
        ...
        </exercise>
        <exercise>
        ...
        </exercise>
    </lesson>
</training>
```

With the XmlPullParser I can find the tags training and lesson, but for lesson I need the containing name. 
I want to collect all exercise parameters for a named lesson i.e. "Set_01".
Within exercise there are some parameters like param count="80". Here I also need what is within param ... />. How to obtain it?

Comment: http://www.javatpoint.com/android-XMLPullParser-tutorial and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code in your parser switch:

```
case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
  String tag=parser.getName();
  if(tag.equals("lesson")){
     String name=parser.getAttributeValue(null,"name");
     ...
  }
```

Comment: It can be so easy! Perfect answer! That's what I'm searching for.